# For loop iterator as variable in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have the following code:

```
import control
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s=control.tf([1,0],1)

freqs=np.logspace(-1,2,5)

plant=1/(s*s)
plant_PI=1/(s*s)*(1+1/10/s)
plant_D=1/(s*s)*(1+s/(1/3))/(1+s/(1*3))/3

compare_responses_gain=["mag_plant","mag_plant_PI","mag_plant_D"]
compare_responses_phase=["phase_plant","phase_plant_PI","phase_plant_D"]

mag_plant,phase_plant,omega_plant=plant.freqresp(freqs)
mag_plant_PI,phase_plant_PI,omega_plant_PI=plant_PI.freqresp(freqs)
mag_plant_D,phase_plant_D,omega_plant_D=plant_D.freqresp(freqs)
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

for i in compare_responses_gain:
    ax1.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((i),axis=(3,)))

for i in compare_responses_phase:
    ax2.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((i),axis=(3,)))

plt.show()
```

What I want is that in the for loop, the "i" works as reference to the mag_plant, etc. variable that is the output of freqresp method. However, this doesn't work since "i" is regarded as string. Does anyone know how to solve this? I know I can just do the assignments without a for loop but I want to learn a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can get the value bound to a global variable with `globals`. After the `for i in compare_responses_gain:`, you can get the value with `val = globals()[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a list of the return values instead of strings:

```
compare_responses_gain=[mag_plant,mag_plant_PI,mag_plant_D]
```

In fact, I'd take this a step further and put your original `plant_*` varialbes in a list:

```
plants = [plant, plant_PI, plant_D]
```

Now you can plot all the data in a single loop:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

for plant in plants:
    mag, phase = plant.freqresp(freqs)
    ax1.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((mag),axis=(3,)))
    ax2.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((phase),axis=(3,)))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add those variables to your list.

```
compare_responses_gain  = []
compare_responses_phase = []

mag_plant,phase_plant,omega_plant=plant.freqresp(freqs)

compare_responses_gain.append(mag_plant)
compare_responses_phase.append(mag_phase)
#.....so on
```

Then loop through the list

Comment: For your solution, you need to initialize an empty list: `compare_responses_gain = []`.

Comment: If the OP isn't careful, they will append to the existing list of strings, so I suggest editing your answer to include this detail.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple variables used the same way, a collection such as a `list` or `dict` can help organize them. Instead of writing variable names in a list and trying to associate them with variables in the module namespace, just put the thing you want to process in a collection from the beginning.

Since a simple index into a list doesn't make it immediately clear what value is being used, you can use a `dict`, a `class` or (in this case) a `namedtuple` to give names to values. This aids in the self documentation of the code.

In this example, the formulas are placed in a `dict` which makes it easy to put the calculations in a list and plot from that list.

```
import control
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple

PlantFreqResp = namedtuple("PlantFreqResp", ["mag", "phase", "omega"])

s=control.tf([1,0],1)

freqs=np.logspace(-1,2,5)

# if you care about the formula names, use a dict
plant_formulas = [1/(s*s),                 # plant
    1/(s*s)*(1+1/10/s),                    # plant_PI
    1/(s*s)*(1+s/(1/3))/(1+s/(1*3))/3]     # plant_D
    
plant_freqs = [PlantFreqResp(*formula.freqresp(freqs)) 
    for formula in plant_formulas]

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

for freqs in plant_freqs:
    ax1.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((freqs.mag),axis=(3,)))
    ax2.plot(freqs,np.squeeze((i=freqs.phase),axis=(3,)))

plt.show()
```